# Is there a way to set a variable in a PostgreSQL statment that can be used in a file path name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I.E.

In the following statment

```
COPY "TableName"
FROM 'MyVARIABLE/filename.csv';
```

Can I set my variable with something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only with procedural language not plain sql.

```
create function copyin( _tablename name, _filename text )
returns void
language plpgsql as $this$
declare sql text;
begin
  sql := 'COPY ' || quote_ident(_tablename) || ' FROM ' || quote_literal(_filename);
  execute sql;
  return;
end;
$this$;

SELECT copyin( 'froobles', '/tmp/froobles.csv' );
```

Comment: In such cases as this, it is, I believe, vital to remember not to expose people to [situations like the one poor Little Bobby Tables once ended up in](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Andriy, you are soo right. Fixed my code - now immune to Mom exploit.